# May I return state from a CQRS Command?

Tags: architecture, cqrs

I just learned about CQRS and have been analyzing my existing code, looking for places where I violate or apply CQRS.

So far I haven't found any places where a query is changing state.
However, many commands modify state and return a data object representing the updated state.
For example: An angular client makes an HTTP request to `/api/message.post`.  The user's id is attached to the request by the HTTP server (based on the HTTP headers) and passed to a microservice that handles `message.post` commands. The result of the command handler is `{ok: false}` or `{ok: true, message: {_id: "xyz", text: "new" ...}}` and the response object is proxied from the microservice back to Angular by the HTTP server.

Is returning state from a command a violation of CQRS?
Should I return only "ok: true/false" from the command, then make a second request to get the new message? If so, why?
Is it worth the overhead if the request/responses are happening through http from a browser?

*edit* The reason I have the data I need at the end of my command is, my read and write models are currently identical. I do understand that in the future I can apply a write model for commands and a read model for queries, at which point it no longer makes sense to return the data the command wrote.

Comment: I do not think that the **command handler** returns that. The command is send to the command bus and after that you can return the the data read from the read model. If something went wrong there should be an exception

Comment: It is not really CQRS if you are using the same model for read and write. Just run the query immediately after you run the command since the data changes are going to be immediate.

CQRS works the best when collaboration is involved (ex: ticket sales, comments on the same article, etc) or the operation can be deferred (ex: allow a user to cancel an order within 5 min before charging the credit card). If it is a single user operation that is processed immediately and requires to display the changes immediately, CQRS might over-complicate things for that part of the domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A command handler *can* return a result (ok, error, some data), but if you're using a service bus, a handler can be executed in a background worker and there will be nobody do handle the result.

In your case, I suppose a command handler is executed directly by the server-side controller so you can return a result. However, if the result you're expecting requires a query which has nothing to do with the command, then it's better to have a different query.

If the result contains the command data itself, then you can return it.

Btw, what you're asking is CQS, not CQRS and in a way it's still the single responsibility principle but in a more specialized form.